How to sort array with values property in jenkins groovy
Not able to sort the following array
tried solutions are listed.
Initial we will have list, by finding the position in another list new list is created
def mylist=[]
def mylistData=[:]
mylistData.id="61628d82a174599d7ae7c61bf6d216f22d5139da"
mylist.add(mylistData)
                    
mylistData=[:]
mylistData.id="0cc18d6d3c93240ab93457063b4974a1270104c0"
mylist.add(mylistData)

mylistData=[:]
mylistData.id="bb007a1c9f594b55662a5b36d5f5b1a7651f3b0f"
mylist.add(mylistData)

mylistData=[:]
mylistData.id="087e7538583ee261944b66491391947d3a002380"
mylist.add(mylistData)

mylistData=[:]
mylistData.id="587ee2b1482509e12d5657bc55db70c9b482eddd"
mylist.add(mylistData)
def list=[]
//linesList=["587ee2b1482509e12d5657bc55db70c9b482eddd"] //contains 50 such values
for(item in mylist){
    item.pos=linesList.findIndexOf { it == item.id }.toInteger()
    list.add(item)
}
list.sort{ it.pos }
println list // list is not sorted
println list.sort{ it.pos }    // list is not sorted

Expected result:
[{id=587ee2b1482509e12d5657bc55db70c9b482eddd, pos=0},{id=bb007a1c9f594b55662a5b36d5f5b1a7651f3b0f, pos=19},  {id=087e7538583ee261944b66491391947d3a002380, pos=37},
{id=61628d82a174599d7ae7c61bf6d216f22d5139da, pos=45},{id=0cc18d6d3c93240ab93457063b4974a1270104c0, pos=54}]

Actual
[{id=61628d82a174599d7ae7c61bf6d216f22d5139da, pos=45}, {id=0cc18d6d3c93240ab93457063b4974a1270104c0, pos=54}, {id=bb007a1c9f594b55662a5b36d5f5b1a7651f3b0f, pos=19}, {id=087e7538583ee261944b66491391947d3a002380, pos=37}, {id=587ee2b1482509e12d5657bc55db70c9b482eddd, pos=0}]

Tried solutions
 list.sort{ it.pos }

Note: I am facing this issue while running inside jenkins

list.sort{ it.pos } should do the job. why do you think it's not working?

Because it didn't change the array, it was as it is

list.sort{ it.pos } is a right way to sort array. we don't see how you are declaring and using the list. the pseudocode that you presented is not runnable. please edit your question and show code to reproduce the issue.

{id=...} are not map literals from groovy - at best that would be a closure.

Can you post an actual example that compiles, instead of a loose collection of random text?

updated with additional code, please revisit

It's a CPS artifact, see here. For your sorting to work you need to put it inside a NonCPS annotated method:
...
println list // list is not sorted
sortByPos(list)
println list // list is sorted

@NonCPS
def sortByPos(l) {
    l.sort { it.pos }
}

Oh, and lists in groovy are sorted in place.

You can opt out of the mutation in place: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(boolean,%20groovy.lang.Closure) (this of course assumes no other Jenkins interference)
